# Can I send data between VB.NET (Windows 7) and java (android) for developing an app?

Tags: java, android, vb.net

--- I want to develop such app which is going to transfer data between android mobile and PC (windows 7). There will my software clients on both android mobile and PC.
--- Is this possible? I mean my there will be a software on android written in java and also on PC written in VB.NET .
 Are these java and VB.NET are possible to use together?
 (android and PC are connected via USB)

---Android app is going to send the data and PC s/w will receive it AND vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to solve this by communicating over a network interface and use REST or another web service and communicate over a standard data structure such as JSON or XML, which both languages - VB.NET and Java - understand.

Don't know about the communication via USB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SOAP web service for VB.net and KSOPA2.jar for your android project.

Comment: I want to transfer data in speed. Over the network it will be slower.